# List Not Updating After Filtering with datetimepicker Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, filtering

I am trying to create a custom filter for my ng-repeat, but when I am using datetimepicker.js it wont update the list based on the criteria. I am fairly new to Javascript, so any pointers / coding practices will be helpful!

### /* Module File */

```
.filter('adminSummaryDataFilter', function () {
    return function (list, selectedStart){
        var output = [];

        var dStart =  new Date(selectedStart);

        angular.forEach(list, function (item) {
            var temp = item.WorkOrderStart.substring(0,item.WorkOrderStart.indexOf(' '));
            var temp2 = item.WorkOrderStart.substring(item.WorkOrderStart.indexOf(' ') + 1, item.WorkOrderStart.length);

            var tempArr = temp.split('-'); //[0] = year, [1] = month, [2] = day
            var temp2Arr = temp2.split(':'); //[0] = hour, [1] = minutes, [2] = seconds

            var newDate = new Date(tempArr[0], tempArr[1], tempArr[2], temp2Arr[0], temp2Arr[1], temp2Arr[2]);

            if (newDate >= dStart) {
                output.push(item);
            }
        });

        return output;
    }
});
```

### /* Controller File */

```
$scope.selectedStart = 0;
$scope.btn_Calendar = function (id) {

$("#" + id).datetimepicker({
   inline: true,
   sideBySide: true
}).on("dp.change", function () {
    $scope.selectedStart = $("#dateTest").val();
});
```

### /* HTML side */

```
<div class="fsTableDetail summary_tableDetail"
     ng-repeat="data in SummaryData | adminSummaryDataFilter:selectedStart"> 
  ....
</div>
```

I want the filter to dynamically update the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
$scope.selectedStart = 0;
$scope.btn_Calendar = function (id) {

$("#" + id).datetimepicker({
   inline: true,
   sideBySide: true
}).on("dp.change", function () {
    $scope.selectedStart = $("#dateTest").val();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

From the Docs:

> AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc...
>
> You can also use [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or **when working with third-party library callbacks.**
>
> [image]
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. Also, I figured out another problem where the indexing of months start at 0.